# mssql for xml includes another xml data

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am using 'FOR XML AUTO' for an XML output. But one of my table's field value is already an XML value so in my output string the above value's `<` and `>` changed to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.
How can I fix it in my query.

Example :-

Table Name : `EMPLOYEE`

`EPMID   EMPNAME        STATUS(varchar)
1        John       <ADP>HR</ADP>`

I used the below query :
`Select * FROM EMPLOYEE FOR XML AUTO`

OUTPUT  : 
`<employee>`
`<empid>1</empid>`
`<empname>john</empname>`
`<status>&lt;ADP&gt;HR &lt;/ADP &gt;</status>`
`</employee>`

I can't change the type of field `status` .

EXPECTED OUTPUT  : 
`<employee>`
`<empid>1</empid>`
`<empname>john</empname>`
`<status><ADP>HR </ADP></status>`
`</employee>`

Comment: You should update your question with some code and data that reproduce what you see and also include the expected output.

Comment: Thanks, Mikael. This was my first question in Stackoverflow.
I updated my question, I searched a lot for this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if you store the xml in a string type field, but not if it is stored in an `xml` typed field.

To resolve it, ensure that your existing xml data is stored in an `xml` type column, not in a `varchar` column, or use `convert(xml,yourfield)` to convert it in your query.

Comment: Thanks podiluska.. I can't change my field type. but convert(xml,yourfield) is helped me.